# Invalid/undefined mediaobject property of QML Camera

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qtmultimedia

I'm trying to create a QML item, defined in C++, that would intercept frames from a QML `Camera` before they are displayed by a `VideoOutput`. Something like:

```
Window {
    Camera {
        id: camera
    }

    MyFrameinterceptor {
        id: myprocessing
        source: camera.mediaObject
    }

    VideoOutput {
        id: feedback
        source: myprocessing
    }
}
```

According to [this comment](http://kunalmaemo.blogspot.fr/2013/06/using-qml-camera-and-passing-image-to-c.html?showComment=1370822658855#c5185691871090913285), the [mediaObject property](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-camera.html#mediaObject-prop) of a `Camera` item can be used to access the C++ part of the `Camera`.

However, when I try to access the mediaObject from QML, e.g. with

```
Text {
    text: qsTr(camera.mediaObject.objectName)
}
```

I get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'objectName' of undefined`
When I try to use the camera.mediaObject property from C++, I get similar messages letting me think that mediaObject is undefined, uninitialized or not existing.

I'm new to Qt, so I may miss something really stupid, like starting the camera or what not... But I have the same problem with a `MediaPlayer` item

How can I access the mediaObject of a QML Camera from C++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tripped into this a couple of times as well, I resolved it like so:

```
QObject * obj = rootview->rootObject()->findChild<QObject *>("camera");
QVariant mediaObject = obj->property("mediaObject");
QCamera * camera = qvariant_cast<QCamera *>(mediaObject);
```

I then use a `QVideoRendererControl` to assign a subclass of `QAbstractVideoSurface` to process frames.