# How can I integrate QML MediaPLayer with C++ side

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qmediaplayer

I have developed a QML based video player program using MediaPlayer element. The program has most of basic functionality of a video player(play,pause,vol up/down,forward,bakcward etc.). My next task is add subtitle to a video and I need to use metaObject method of MediaPlayer element but QML side does allow that funtionality, it says:

```
Note: This property is not accessible from QML.
```

There is a description in the document related metaObject which is confusing my mind:

```
mediaObject : variant
This property holds the native media object.

It can be used to get a pointer to a QMediaPlayer object in order to integrate with C++ code.

QObject *qmlMediaPlayer; // The QML MediaPlayer object
QMediaPlayer *player = qvariant_cast<QMediaPlayer *>(qmlMediaPlayer->property("mediaObject"));
```

What is this supposed to mean? How can I integrate QML MediaPlayer with C++? Any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend on how exactly you launch the QML application. Suppose it is set up like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   // Q(Gui)Application setup...
    
   QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
   engine.load(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));

   // ...
}
```

And somewhere inside the QML object hierarchy you have a MediaPlayer:

```js
MediaPlayer {
    objectName: "player"
    // ...
}
```

It's important to set the `objectName` property, so that you can look up the MediaPlayer instance by this name in the C++ code. After loading the QML document as above, the engine has a single root object you can search with `findChild` or `findChildren` (adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24895680/1719926)):

```
auto qmlPlayer = engine.rootObjects()[0]->findChild<QObject*>("player");
auto player = qvariant_cast<QMediaPlayer*>(qmlPlayer->property("mediaObject"));
// use the QMediaPlayer*
```

Comment: Thank you, I am very greatful! After several tries I have found that the objectName must be written in quotes(objectName: "player"). Could you correct your answer?

Comment: @quteguy You're right, sorry about that!